# Python ASCII Reading tables

Tags: python, ascii

I'm really sorry for asking probably silly question but I have spend half a day and could not find reasonable solution.
I have ASCII file:

```
      "X"           "Z"             "Y"
   285807.2      -1671.056        2405.91
   285807.2      -1651.162       2394.932
   285807.2      -1631.269       2383.962
   285807.2      -1611.375       2372.988
   285807.2      -1591.481        2362.01
   285807.2      -1571.587       2351.01
```

.............................................
~1 000 000 rows

And I normaly read it:

```
from astropy.io import ascii

data =ascii.read('C:\\Users\\Protoss\\Desktop\\Ishodnik1.dat')
print (data)
```

But How could I deal with columns? For instance sum each rows or make an average value,  etc only from columns Z and Y? As I understand I have to converts all my date to list of float valuse except for  headliner and then to write new ASCII file, doesn't it?

Comment: Use `np.genfromtxt`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It might be a misspell of "data"

Comment: please edit your question to show us the python output of `print(data)`. ATM it is incomplete.

Comment: Output of print(data) is the table. It looks exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

What I did. I separated columns and added to different lists. Now I have got access for different columns:

```
import numpy as np
    with open('C:\\Users\\Protoss\\Desktop\\Ishodnik.dat' ,'r') as f:
        header1 = f.readline()    
        X_list=[]
        Z_list=[]
        V_list=[]
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            X = (float(columns[0]))
            Z = (float(columns[1]))
            V = (float(columns[2]))
            X_list.append(X)
            Z_list.append(Z)
            V_list.append(V)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to treat the file as CSV and use `Sniffer` to autodetect the format:

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\Protoss\\Desktop\\Ishodnik1.dat', 'r') as f:
    # Sniff to autodetect the format
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024))
    f.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect)

    # Read line by line and store as list of tuples
    data = []
    header = tuple(next(reader))
    for row in reader:
        data.append(tuple(row))
```